# daHow to Specify !important to entire css class

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am jquery ui tabs in my web application.

I have a button class, that syles my button in application.

But, when i am putting that button inside the tab , it's style is over ridden by the jquery ui css.

One, possible option is using `!important` to stop being over rided. but, it can be applied only to a single style inside a class.

is it not possible to specify !important to entire class?

If not, what is the other way to stop this over riding of CSS?

**Updated:**

```
.button 
{
    padding-top: 2px ;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    color: #6688A4;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border: 1px double #003C74;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I am using jquery ui css file for jquery ui elements.

The above button class is being over ridden by the below class:

```
.ui-button
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-right: .1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible; /* removes extra width in IE */
}
```

Comment: The answer might be to ensure the selectivity of your rule is big enough. But usually this happens when the CSS is badly managed. Can you reproduce your problem in a minimal fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want what you have in `.button` to have priority over what you have in `.ui-button`, you can increase the specificity by changing the rule from

```
.button {
```

to

```
.ui-button.button, .button {
```

[An article on specificity](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity)

Extract :

> Specificity is a mechanism within the CSS cascade that aids conflict
>   resolution. The concept of specificity states that when two or more
>   declarations that apply to the same element, and set the same
>   property, have the same importance and origin, the declaration with
>   the most specific selector will take precedence.

[W3.org specificity formula](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#specificity)

Comment: @Dystroy..Thanks..It worked. Can you please explain in breif about this change?

Comment: @Avinash I added two links in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually which ever is loaded last overrides the other.  Can you make sure that the style you want to override is loaded after the other one in your HTML?